# Read pixel of a L*a*b color space image

Tags: c++, opencv, lab-color-space

From [opencv documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html#color_convert_rgb_lab) i found that the L*a*b* color space has limited value for each variable as following :

```
   0 < L < 100
-127 < a < 127 
-127 < b < 127
```

I wrote a code which read and convert an image of type BGR to L*a*b* color space. When i show value of L,a and b i found that values are out of range (all of them)

For example in a pixel (y,x) the value of b is 150 but from the opencv 2.4.13 documentation b must be between -127 and 127.
The code is the following :

```
   #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
   #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
   #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
   #include <iostream>

   using namespace cv;
   using namespace std;


   int main(int argc, char** argv){

    Mat input, Lab_img;

    input = imread("E:\\Walid\\Images\\b2.jpg");


    cvtColor(input, Lab_img, CV_BGR2Lab);
    namedWindow("ORIGINAL", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("Lab", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);



    for (int y = 0; y < Lab_img.rows; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < Lab_img.cols; x++)
        {
            Vec3b intensity = Lab_img.at<Vec3b>(y, x);
            double L = intensity.val[0];
            double a = intensity.val[1];
            double b = intensity.val[2];
            cout << b << std::endl;
        }
    }


    imshow("ORIGINAL", input);
    imshow("Lab", Lab_img);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: You can check the source code. a and b are offseted by 128. And I found I forgot most details.

Comment: Added link to the relevant documentation that the OP has mis-interpreted (or not read far enough).

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle Please stop leaving that comment each time you make an edit. You do not need to explain your edits via comments.

Comment: @meagar SO required me to do that before I hit 2K reputation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is reference for [cvtColor](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) In section RGB <-> CIE L*a*b* it says:

> This outputs 0 <= L <= 100, -127 <= a <= 127, -127 <= b <= 127 . **The
>   values are then converted to the destination data type:** For 8-bit
>   images L = L*255/100, a = a + 128, b = b + 128.

Comment: Thnx a lot so if i have b = -50 i must convert it to b = 78 by adding 128 to old value.

Comment: Why not just cast the `unsigned char` to `signed char`, before it's (implicitly) cast to `double`?